# $ Object doesn't support property or method 'live'

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have some script here that is throwing an error in IE, because of the method live. The testing website URL is @ http://8020demo.com/ReadyRange

I have read numerous fixes, and tried various ways to fix it, but no luck so far - any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

- I am using the latest Jquery version 1.10.2
- I am also using the Jquery migrate 1.2.1

Current code:

```
function slider(selector,xml)
{

// pre-loads slider images into cache (*used for a smooth slide transition on initial page load)
slide1 = new Image(960,455);
slide1.src = "./img/carouselSlide1.jpg";

slide2 = new Image(960,455);
slide2.src = "./img/carouselSlide2.jpg";

slide3 = new Image(960,455);
slide3.src = "./img/carouselSlide3.jpg";

function Slide2Next(selector,count,content,items,slideID)
{   
    if(slideID>0) count = slideID;
    else if(count<items) count++;
    else count = 1; // reached the last slide, get back to first

    $(selector+' .splash_content').animate({opacity:'toggle'},250, function(){
    // faded out, changing content
    $(selector+ ' .splash_content').html(content[count]).fadeIn();
    $(selector+' .splash_controls a.selected').removeAttr("class");
    $(selector+' .splash_controls a[rel='+count+']').attr("class","selected");
    });

    return count;
}

// slider
var items = 0;
var content = new Array(3);
var control = '';
var count = 1;

$.get(xml, function(data)
{ // get contents from xml

    $(data).find('slide').each(function()
    {
        // populate array
        items++;
        var $slide = $(this); 
        content[items] = $slide.find('content').text();
        // create controls
        if(items==1) control = control + '<a href="#" class="selected" rel="'+items+'"></a>';
        else control = control + '<a href="#" rel="'+items+'"></a>';
    });

    $(selector+' .splash_content').html(content[count]);

    // add controls

    $(selector+' .splash_controls').html(control);
});

// control is clicked
$(selector+' .splash_controls a').live('click',function (){
    var slideID = $(this).attr('rel');
    count = Slide2Next(selector,count,content,items,slideID);
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
    slideInterval = setInterval(function() {count = Slide2Next(selector,count,content,items)}, 10000 );
    return false;
});

var slideInterval = setInterval(function() {count = Slide2Next(selector,count,content,items)}, 10000 );
}
```

The problem is coming from this part of the coding:

```
// control is clicked
$(selector+' .splash_controls a').live('click',function (){
    var slideID = $(this).attr('rel');
    count = Slide2Next(selector,count,content,items,slideID);
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
    slideInterval = setInterval(function() {count =    Slide2Next(selector,count,content,items)}, 10000 );
return false;
});
```

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using? live was deprecated in 1.7

Comment: you are using Jquery migrate so i guess error comes from `selector` variable, should be a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in jQuery 1.9.  You'll want to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.  The mose immediate fix for your code would be to do this

```
$(document).on('click', selector+' .splash_controls a', function (){
```

but of course that will cause **all** events anywhere in your document to be examined, which is sub-optimal (and also exactly how live worked).  So if these anchors will always be inside of some parent container (that's present when this code runs) you should do this instead

```
$('#parentContainer').on('click', selector+' .splash_controls a', function (){
```

Comment: This code $('#parentContainer').on('click', selector+'.splash_controls a', function (){ got it done. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated, as stated:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

so try [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(selector+' .splash_controls a').on('click',function (){
    var slideID = $(this).attr('rel');
    count = Slide2Next(selector,count,content,items,slideID);
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
    slideInterval = setInterval(function() {count =    Slide2Next(selector,count,content,items)}, 10000 );
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(selector+' .splash_controls a').on('click',function (){
    var slideID = $(this).attr('rel');
    count = Slide2Next(selector,count,content,items,slideID);
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
    slideInterval = setInterval(function() {count =    Slide2Next(selector,count,content,items)}, 10000 );
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't; `live` was deprecated in 1.7, and AFAIK was finally removed.

http://api.jquery.com/category/removed/

Answer (score 0):

If the click still isn't working, you can maybe try this:

```
$(selector+' .splash_controls').on('click', 'a', function(){ *your stuff here* });
```

Best of luck!